# Is there anyway to make Double slit experiment in Blender Geometry Nodes . I saw dynamic paint version but unfortunately is not that good

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

The issue is wave are small i want to customise amplitude of the wave . I want to show in 3D  . Will be very thankfull if anybody know how to do in Geometry nodes or show better approach
[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F152553%2Fdiffraction-of-a-wave-passing-through-double-slits&psig=AOvVaw0BiXOeYZXvnpQgUCcAVuez&ust=1700504597430000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCIDujLXX0IIDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE]

Comment: i already saw version someone uploaded here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152553/diffraction-of-a-wave-passing-through-double-slits . issue is its wave amplitude very small i palyed with dynamic paint parameter but can't able to achieve satisfied result